# How to start content with the starting with flex

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to start my whole content with after player time-code but i'm not able to achieve it

[image]

here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100)

here is what i have tried:

```css
.conatiner{
   border: 1px solid #eaeaed;
   padding: 5px 12px;
}

.player-action{
   display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="conatiner">
   <div class="player-action">
       <div class="icon">
          <svg data-v-3805f2dc="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="#01868c" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-play-fill">
                  <path data-v-3805f2dc="" d="m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"></path>
               </svg>
       </div>
      <div class="timestamp">00:12.12 - 00:14.01</div>
   </div>
  <div class="content">
      The National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA /ˈnæsə/) is an independent agency of the U.S. federal government responsible for the civil space program, aeronautics research, and space research. Established in 1958, NASA succeeded the National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics (NACA) to give the U.S. space development effort a distinctly civilian orientation, emphasizing peaceful applications in space science.[4][5][6] NASA has since led most American space exploration, including Project Mercury, Project Gemini, the 1968–1972 Apollo Moon landing missions, the Skylab space station, and the Space Shuttle. NASA currently supports the International Space Station and oversees the development of the Orion spacecraft and the Space Launch System for the crewed lunar Artemis program, the Commercial Crew spacecraft, and the planned Lunar Gateway space station.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can move your player in the content div and give it a display:inline-flex behavior. BTW your codepen link shows an empty pen - you can remove it

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.player-action { float: left; }`:

```css
.conatiner {
  border: 1px solid #eaeaed;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  display: flow-root;
  --player-action-height: 32px;
  --content-font-size: 16px;
  --content-line-height: 1.4;
}

.player-action {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  height: var(--player-action-height);
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.content {
  font-size: var(--content-font-size);
  line-height: var(--content-line-height);
  /* vertical center align */
  margin-top: calc(.5 * var(--player-action-height) - .5 * (var(--content-font-size) * var(--content-line-height)));
}
```

```html
<div class="conatiner">
   <div class="player-action">
       <div class="icon">
          <svg data-v-3805f2dc="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="#01868c" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-play-fill">
                  <path data-v-3805f2dc="" d="m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"></path>
               </svg>
       </div>
      <div class="timestamp">00:12.12 - 00:14.01</div>
   </div>
  <div class="content">
      The National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA /ˈnæsə/) is an independent agency of the U.S. federal government responsible for the civil space program, aeronautics research, and space research. Established in 1958, NASA succeeded the National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics (NACA) to give the U.S. space development effort a distinctly civilian orientation, emphasizing peaceful applications in space science.[4][5][6] NASA has since led most American space exploration, including Project Mercury, Project Gemini, the 1968–1972 Apollo Moon landing missions, the Skylab space station, and the Space Shuttle. NASA currently supports the International Space Station and oversees the development of the Orion spacecraft and the Space Launch System for the crewed lunar Artemis program, the Commercial Crew spacecraft, and the planned Lunar Gateway space station.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but 2nd line is having some gaps why ?

Comment: As you can see I have created some css variables. So you can either decrease `--player-action-height` or increase `--content-line-height` so that the second line is moved under `.player-action`. Updated my answer - now reduced `--player-action-height` a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve a column layout you should make the `.container` a flexbox container as well.

There is an [excellent guide to flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) that explains all the properties of the parent and children side-by-side.

```css
.conatiner {
  border: 1px solid #eaeaed;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  column-gap: 12px;
}

.player-action {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* optionally prevent this flex-child from shrinking */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="conatiner">
  <div class="player-action">
    <div class="icon">
      <svg data-v-3805f2dc="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="#01868c" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-play-fill">
                  <path data-v-3805f2dc="" d="m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"></path>
               </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="timestamp">00:12.12 - 00:14.01</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    The National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA /ˈnæsə/) is an independent agency of the U.S. federal government responsible for the civil space program, aeronautics research, and space research. Established in 1958, NASA succeeded the National
    Advisory Committee for Aeronautics (NACA) to give the U.S. space development effort a distinctly civilian orientation, emphasizing peaceful applications in space science.[4][5][6] NASA has since led most American space exploration, including Project
    Mercury, Project Gemini, the 1968–1972 Apollo Moon landing missions, the Skylab space station, and the Space Shuttle. NASA currently supports the International Space Station and oversees the development of the Orion spacecraft and the Space Launch
    System for the crewed lunar Artemis program, the Commercial Crew spacecraft, and the planned Lunar Gateway space station.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a gap on left side i want all the gap to be filled just like for image how we fill

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Player and Content</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            border: 1px solid #eaeaed;
            padding: 5px 12px;
        }

        .player-action {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .content {
            margin-top: 10px; /* Add margin to separate content from player section */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="player-action">
            <div class="icon">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28" fill="#01868c" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-play-fill">
                    <path d="m11.596 8.697-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="timestamp">00:12.12 - 00:14.01</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            The National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA /ˈnæsə/) is an independent agency of the U.S. federal government responsible for the civil space program, aeronautics research, and space research. Established in 1958, NASA succeeded the National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics (NACA) to give the U.S. space development effort a distinctly civilian orientation, emphasizing peaceful applications in space science.[4][5][6] NASA has since led most American space exploration, including Project Mercury, Project Gemini, the 1968–1972 Apollo Moon landing missions, the Skylab space station, and the Space Shuttle. NASA currently supports the International Space Station and oversees the development of the Orion spacecraft and the Space Launch System for the crewed lunar Artemis program, the Commercial Crew spacecraft, and the planned Lunar Gateway space station.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).